# Run Spark over Hadoop

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, apache-spark

In my local machine, I have installed scala, spark, hadoop. I have done one sample program of word count using spark with maven. Now I have to do these things over Hadoop using spark?. How can I do this??

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html) you can find the docs about how to run Spark on YARN. This means that Spark will use the same resource manager of your Hadoop distribution.

If, instead, you meant only that you want Spark to be run using files stored through HDFS, than you can simply run Spark in standalone mode and specify the `hdfs://` URL of the files he has to deal with. In this case, you just have to set the Spark `master` to `local` and run your application. Instruction about how to install and submit applications in standalone mode are [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html)